# Fret buzzing sound

Tags: acoustic-guitar, buzz

I need help with my acoustic guitar because it keeps buzzing , 
any tips to stop it forever ? and how to distinguish if this is a bad quality guitar or there is something need fix ? .
The neck looks straight and the nut on the guitar also looks fine 
I'm confused.

Comment: If you need to know if this is a bad quality guitar, you really need to take it to a technician who can do a proper setup. Or find a local guitar player who can have a play and check it out.

Comment: Do you have any friends who are decent guitar players?  One thing you should consider is to let an experienced guitar player play your guitar and see if it buzzes when they play it.  If not, it may be your playing technique that needs refinement. Not to worry, we have all been there.  It get's better over time with practice.  If so - they might be able to identify the issue and suggest how to correct it.  There are so many different things that can cause "buzzing" that it would be hard for anyone to say with any certainty what is causing the buzzing you are experiencing.  Good luck with it.

Answer (score 1):

There are several possible sources of buzzing on a guitar (or any stringed instrument).  If you're good with tools and not afraid of ruining your guitar you could try to fix it yourself; otherwise take it to a qualified person.  The most usual reasons for buzzing strings on a guitar are: one or more frets are too high or too low, which can be a problem either with the frets or the neck; the notches in the nut are too low or too wide at the acoustic end of the string; or the string is bad.  Which strings buzz, played open or at what fret?  It's possible to true the frets or correct the nut if you have the right tools and some experience, but if not, take it to an expert.

Comment: There are other Q&A on this stack exchange which cover this, but one additional thing Eva can try is to look for anything loose on the instrument: paper labels, the kerfing on the inside of an acoustic etc, all can rattle when playing. With an acoustic, just put an ear close to it and rap the back with your knuckles, listening for any vibrations.

Comment: action 0.6   any suggestions ?

Comment: Eva: tell us exactly what buzzes when.  Which sting, open and/or played at what fret.

Comment: especially fret 5 ,6,7,8,9 ... And the  A chord make terrible buzzing sound

Comment: 0.6 inches? Feet? Kilometers? cm? mm? Potatoes? :) Also, the action may not be the issue; if it's an older guitar, it may need a neck reset. I'm another person saying 'take it to a technician'.

Comment: @pete it's not an old guitar i bought it 1/1/2016 .. and the action 0.6 potatoes ...just kidding :) 0.6 cm

Comment: @eva: If you purchased it from a retail store, they quite often do complimentary adjustments on newer guitars - sounds like it's just adjusting to the humidity in your home, and should be a quick fix.

Answer (score 0):

**#### Ways to Fix the buzzing sound on your Guitar**

***Note***: Any loose part on your guitar may buzz audibly, when certain notes are played.

- Say, suppose you knock on the body of the guitar and the buzz appears to come from the neck, then there’s probably something loose on the **neck** or **headstock**.
- If the noise or the buzz occurs only when you tap on the back, there’s probably a brace loose inside.
- When the guitar is a about *5-6* months old, tighten the nuts on the **headstock** as the wood compresses slowly with time.
- Adjustment of the **truss rod** - Tightening the **truss rod** nut would be enough to keep it from coming unscrewed and allowing the washer to become loose and avoid the buzz as well.

  [image]               [image]